# "step by step" applying a function to each element of a list

Tags: python

There's code:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def func(a):
    return 10 * a

result = list(map(func, nums))
print(result)
```

With result:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
```

How to apply a function to the first element of the list, show the result, and then apply to the others in the same way?

And the result should look something like this:

```
10
20
30
40
```

Comment: have you tried anything at all??

Comment: You could just do a for loop that prints each element once map() aplied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a loop for this since `list(map())` will return the full list rather than print "one by one"

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def func(a):
    return 10 * a

for n in nums:
    print(func(n))
```

Or this, which will also run your `func` and print the returned value, one value at a time

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def func(a):
    return 10 * a

for n in map(func, nums):
    print(n)
```

Comment: Similar effect - ```print(*map(func, nums))```   w/o *loop*.  ...-;)

Comment: Yeah, I always forget print accepts multiple arguments, but that would not print on multiple lines